# How can i enable a java script when a button is clicked(html)

Tags: html

I want to enable a java script when i press a button.
for example, the java script is -

```
<div id="miniclip-game-embed" data-game-name="upipe-skateboard" data-theme="1" data-width="600" data-height="457"></div>
<script src="http://www.miniclip.com/js/game-embed.js"></script>
```

and when i click the button U pipe,this java script should get enabled
The button and enabling code should be in html

Comment: You will need to use a little bit of javascript to load/initialise/enable the main game javascript when the button is clicked. Is that OK? Do you have jQuery available?

Comment: Also, your example HTML doesn't show the button - could you add that?

Answer (score 0):

This element write a iframe in div.

You can create a outstanding div, if you download and modify game-embed.js (iframe element) the event would fire at all times.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; width: 600px; height: 457px;" onclick="this.style.display='none'; /* put your action */"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 900;" id="miniclip-game-embed" data-game-name="upipe-skateboard" data-theme="1" data-width="600" data-height="457"> </div>
  <script src="http://www.miniclip.com/js/game-embed.js"> </script>
</div>
```

Try this!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try.

First of all you might need some kind of a reusable script injector. Below is an example that takes a URL as parameter and loads a script located at that URL.

```
function injectScript(src) {
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

    scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptElement.language = 'javascript';
    scriptElement.src = src;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
}
```

Next, you probably need to enable not only the game, but the `<div>` container where it is going to be displayed. So here's a little helper that you can customise to your liking:

```
function enableTheGame(containerId, scriptSource) {
    var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
    if (container) {
        container.className = 'enabled'; // can be anything, e.g. style.display='block'
        injectScript(scriptSource); // here's our injector
    }
}
```

Now, provided that your button has an id, let's attach to it an event listener that will enable the game. Note that it's important to wait for the page to finish loading.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var button = document.getElementById('SomeButton');
    if (button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            enableTheGame('miniclip-game-embed', 'http://www.miniclip.com/js/game-embed.js');
        });
    }
});
```

The above examples can be improved. For example, the last function could take a look at the button's `data-...` properties and decide which script to load and where to.